# Define Different Business Hrs for different days in Python businesstimedelta

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I am trying to calculate the business hours between various timestamps in Python.
Normally, I'd define the work hours as below:

```
import datetime
import pytz
import businesstimedelta

# Define a working day
workday = businesstimedelta.WorkDayRule(
    start_time=datetime.time(9),
    end_time=datetime.time(17),
    working_days=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

However, there are certain days that have different business hours than the rest.
In my case, Mon-Fri is `9-17` while Sat is `9-14`

I want to set this in a way that if I am calculating the working hours between say a date like

```
2021-12-18 and 2021-12-20
```

It applies different working hours for the days in between as they are defined.

Is there a way to do this in `businesstimedelta` and if not, is there an alternative?

Comment: Can you please explain what you have attempted to solve this issue? Why your solution doesn't works?

Comment: Actually, I have managed to figure it out. I just defined another schedule as below:

saturday= businesstimedelta.WorkDayRule(
    start_time=datetime.time(9),
    end_time=datetime.time(14),
    working_days=[5])

And then passed both the schedules when calculating the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out.
The solution is to define both schedules

```
workday = businesstimedelta.WorkDayRule(
    start_time=datetime.time(9),
    end_time=datetime.time(17),
    working_days=[0,1, 2, 3, 4])

saturday = businesstimedelta.WorkDayRule(
    start_time=datetime.time(9),
    end_time=datetime.time(14),
    working_days=[5])
```

Then pass both while getting the time difference:

```
businesshrs = businesstimedelta.Rules([workday, saturday])
```